# Doublet derivation

Tags: calculus, fluid-dynamics

I'm just following these notes. I am not sure how they went from the third line to the fourth line where it is expanded. Any chance someone could point me in the right direction? Thanks :-)

[image]

Comment: Is it expanding the denominator with the power series?

Comment: Geometric series even

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examining the log term we have

$\large\log\left(\frac{1+\epsilon/z}{1-\epsilon/z}\right)=\log\left((1+\epsilon/z)\frac{1}{1-\epsilon/z}\right)$

Now the fraction $\frac{1}{1-\epsilon/z}$ has the following Taylor series expansion

$\large \frac{1}{1-\epsilon/z}=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\epsilon/z)^n\sim 1+(\epsilon/z)+O\left((\epsilon^2/z^2\right))$

Interestingly, as per the OP's comment, the left hand side of the above equation can be regarded as a sum to infinity of a geometric progression of the terms on the right.

Thus we have

$\large\log\left(\frac{1+\epsilon/z}{1-\epsilon/z}\right)=\log\left\{(1+\epsilon/z)\left[1+(\epsilon/z)+O\left((\epsilon^2/z^2\right)\right]\right\}$

Comment: Thank you, that's what I thought. I spotted it after I posted the question!

Comment: Well spotted - and a very good way of looking at the series expansion of the fraction term.